# Sorting an ArrayList of Names using a Comparator that sorts by length

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I'm having trouble with my code. I tried using Strings for the arraylist but it doesn't work. When I put the class name in the arraylist, it only prints a different value. I made a class to get the length because doing it in the comparator didn't work; it just gives me a cannot find symbol error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<Name>
{
    public int compare(Name n1, Name n2)
    {
        return n1.getLength()-n2.getLength();
    }
}

public class Name implements Comparable<Name>
{
    public static String name;

    public Name(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public int compareTo(Name that)
    {
        return this.name.compareTo(that.name);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getLength()
    {
        return this.name.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {   
        ArrayList<Name> N = new ArrayList<>(5);     
        BufferedReader keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter Name: ");
        //String n = keyIn.readLine();


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {       
            String n = keyIn.readLine();
            N.add(new Name(n));
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
        Collections.sort(N);

        for(int i=0;i<N.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(N.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        Collections.sort(N, new StringLengthComparator());

        for(int i=0;i<N.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(N.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

[Error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421JD.png) for ArrayList<\String> N = new ArrayList<\String>

[Error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Z4j.png) for ArrayList <\Name> N = new ArrayList<>(5)

Comment: Help us help you - share the exact text of the error and the line you get it on

Comment: you have declared `name` as `public static String name;` static? I think that's causing whatever problems you're facing.

Comment: As @Ryotsu already pointed out, don't declare the name member as static, change the declaration to `private String name;`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort by length and alphabetically by choice you need 2 comperators and choose each time which one to use, by `N.sort(new X)`, where X is the name of the comperator class you want.  
You don't need `Collections.sort()`:

```
class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<Name> {
    public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
        return n1.getLength()-n2.getLength();
    }
}

class StringCommonComparator implements Comparator<Name> {
    public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
        return n1.getName().compareTo(n2.getName());
    }
}

public class Name {
    private String name;

    public Name(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return this.name.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Name> N = new ArrayList<>(5);
        BufferedReader keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter Name: ");
        String n = keyIn.readLine();
        N.add(new Name(n));

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            String name = keyIn.readLine();
            N.add(new Name(name));
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Compare by Length");
        N.sort(new StringLengthComparator());

        for(int i=0;i<N.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(N.get(i).name);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Compare by String");
        N.sort(new StringCommonComparator());

        for(int i=0;i<N.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(N.get(i).name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for both to exist? I want them to sort both alphabetically and by length.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<Name> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
        return n1.getLength() - n2.getLength();
    }
}

public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
    public static String name;

    public Name(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Name that) {
        return this.name.compareTo(that.name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return this.name.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Name> N = new ArrayList<>(5);
        BufferedReader keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter Name: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String n = keyIn.readLine();
            N.add(new Name(n));
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
        Collections.sort(N);

        for (Name name : N) {
            System.out.println(name.getName());
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        Collections.sort(N, new StringLengthComparator());

        for (int i = 0; i < N.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(N.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```